# How do i solo with both scale and chords?

Tags: chord-progressions, key, improvisation, solos

I know how to play pentatonic, major and minor scale.
The question in solo i have chord progression like: C G Am F.

Then i play C major scale, i could play are C major chord in all shapes.

But how about G, Am and F chords?

I have tried to play G , Am and F chords during the solo.

Can i play `G F Am` chords while soloing in key of C? or i have to change to use scale of G before playing G chord?
For example i play C major scale until i get G note and play G chord there but it sounds so weird.

Few video example of some jazz solo with scale and chords

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're a little mixed up. The question itself is ambiguous. I don't believe you want to play **chords** during your solo, but that's what seems to be asked. You appear to be confusing scales, chords and possibly keys, and they're all different, although related. I'm vtc until the question is more clear and I can provide a helpful answer.

Comment: No i'm not, you could see this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wGSOngQGg or any jazz solo, they play scale mix with chords

Comment: Please read the comments, Tom - you do seem a little mixed up. Please have a think about what you want to do, and edit your question accordingly to focus on that so we can take it off hold.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem i don't understand, that's what exactly what i asked for. What's mixed up? Please point out, that's chord to play along with scale. This community become so weird, instead of pointing out what's wrong, what's to do, you simply lock it. That's not helpful and against the point of this site.

Comment: It's because at it stands your question is completely unclear. What you have written in the headline question doesn't match the body of the question, which is internally inconsistent, and doesn't match what you just wrote in the comment. We would like to answer a question but it needs to be a valid question that makes sense - see our [about] and [ask] pages

Comment: If your question is just "how do I choose chords to play along with a solo" then we have questions on that. If it is how to play chords and melody at the same time please ask that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't change the scale (the key) with each chord change. For example, you don't change your F note (from the key of C major) to an F# (in the key of G major) over the G chord in your example progression. You *can* do that, but it's not typical for a simple chord progression in a popular music style.

If the chords you're soloing over stay within the key (as those in your example do), then you're "safe" playing notes in that key. I wrote "safe" because you can still play notes from the scale that clash with the chord being played. For example, if you're playing a C note over the G chord, your C note will "clash" with the B note in the chord (G major chord has notes G B D). If your C note is played in passing, briefly, between a B note and a D note (for example), it functions as a passing tone and sounds good.

Learn what notes are in each chord, then practice a solo that stays on chord tones exclusively. That can also mean NOT changing notes as chord changes. F major and C major chords share the note C. You could hold out a C note over that chord change (F->C or C->F) and it will sound "right". (More quotes, because "right" varies with the genre of music.)

Then you can branch out and try adding non-chord-tone notes that sit in a run, or longer notes that extend the chord. For example, if you play a G note over your Am chord, you've essentially extended the chord by adding another third (that's the interval) to make it an Am7 chord.

Solos that sound "smooth", those that are said to "follow the changes", regularly reinforce chord tones at strategic times. The musical pulse has a bit of emphasis (often on the beat), and the solo chooses that instant to land triumphantly on a chord tone. BOOM! Smiles all around.

Comment: i just read about harmonizing. using chords in key while soloing with scale like i do would not guarantee sound good, to find the chord to fit the melody makes it sounds better? For example i should play arpeggio of C G Am F chords while soloing along with chords not all notes in scale?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a route, which brings me quickly to nice reuslts.

1 ) I find it helpful to separate two species: `melody` and `progression`. To simplify let's assume, melody and chords come from the same scale, i.e. you have no chords with notes not-in-scale.

2 ) So one part of soloing is to vary the `melody`. The easist as a beginner is to keep the scale (key). Later, with more experience, you can look for so called `modulation` to move from one key to an other.

If you haven't paid attention to melody in your song so far, it's a good time to do it: what IS your songs melody? Do you play it on your instrument? Do you sing it? And so on.

3 ) Let's assume you came up with two melodies, at least: the original one and a modification or variation. If you play both to:

- exactly the same `chord progression`
- a new `chord progression`

the sound and feel can change quite a lot. So it's up to you to identify the "best" progression for each melody. Which is a matter of taste, preference and logic of music.

**Hint to members: the following is about knowledge, not product**

You can find popular [chord progressions on Hooktheory (free to use so far)](https://www.hooktheory.com/theorytab/common-chord-progressions). It shows you about 20 popular ones, together with song-examples (where the progression occurs in the given song), and an option to change root notes on-line.

By chance you already used the first one mentioned:

[image: 1st progression]

So why not trying one of the next ones, and make them work for your improvisation?

For example, if you want to start a second progression at G AND follow the same progression (`I - V - vi - IV`), either recalculate the pitches (recommended) or change the key to G (lazy approach) to obtain:

G - D -em - C

4 ) Please keep in mind, it's an iterative process and a journey. Which means: very likely you have to adjust both melodies and progressions here and there.

5 ) To "cure" chords you can use chord- and scale tables, like here on [Chord.Rocks on C-major](https://chord.rocks/piano/scales/c-major) : if G sound strange, try G5 (power chord) or any other mentioned (click on the chords button to obtain the notes, unless you know them). Work from there.

6 ) It's always a good idea to review your results (later) from the perspective of music theory. This body-of-knowledge sometimes clarifies things, or raise questions at other times. It may put your ideas into a broader context, and so on.

Comment: this is not what i asked.

Comment: @TomSawyer, so what is your question? If it's just about changing scale/key, see #2), "modulation".

Comment: can i play G F Am chords while soloing in key of C? or i have to change to use scale of G before playing G chord?

Comment: Both is possible. The chords you mention fit the C-major scale, see https://chord.rocks/piano/scales/c-major, i.e. no key changes. It's up to you to decide if it sounds good (enough). // If you need chord adaptations, use the table in the link as a starting point. #5 // If you feel the progression should be different, like jazzy ii-V7, look for progressions (see Hooktheory for non-Jazz progressions) #3. // If you look for good-bad rules, get into harmony.